# JSP Edit text box value

Tags: jsp, request, edit

I am getting problem in edit function.

I wrote code like this

```
<input type="text" name="wendtime" id="wendtime"  value="<%=ExamB.getExam_end_time()%>"></input>
```

I am not getting how to edit in the same Jsp, It should not go next Jsp

For edit button i used  Update

if I click then wendtime value coming null

String strEndtime=request.getParameter("wendtime");

All the code is in the EditExamEndtime.jsp

How can I do edit?

Comment: It'll be easier to help you'll post the full piece of code you're using

Comment: post your code for exact solution

Answer (score 0):

As you are using jsp's ...Once they compiled and dispatched  the values doesn't change until the next compile .. As per your requirement to make it done

Below are the option

1)you need to recompile the page (i.e refresh or  request the page again)

2)If you want to get the value without page refresh use an Ajax request .

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `window.onload()` in your code to set textbox value

```
<script>

function window.onload()
{
  //set textbox value from request.getParameter("wendtime");
   //check document.getElementById("wendtime").value is null or not if null then set textbox value
   document.getElementById("wendtime").value = request.getParameter("wendtime"); 


}

</script>
```

Comment: first time he is setting correctly ..he wants to refresh the value after some time . i think ..

Comment: you set the textbox value from Bean, when it submit then it require Bean value again